# How to use vertx in java to call api 4 times and then proceed

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

```
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id -> {
    //api call
    if (count == 4){
        vertx.cancelTime(id); 
    }
});
```

Now the problem is I don't want a fix 1000 ms time, I just want to call the api 4 times and then go with final api response for further processing , please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a recursive approach.

Therefore you can implement something like this as an convenient entrypoint

```
private Future<YourResultType> callApiNTimes(final int repetitions) {
    final Promise<YourResultType> p = Promise.promise();

    recursiveApiCalls(p, 0, repetitions);

    return p.future();
}
```

Recursion implemented as following

```
private void recursiveApiCalls(final Promise<YourResultType> p, final int counter, final int maxRepetitions) {
    yourRawApiCall().onComplete(reply -> {
        if (reply.failed()) {
            p.fail(reply.cause());
            return;
        }

        if (counter < maxRepetitions) {
            recursiveApiCalls(p, counter + 1, maxRepetitions);
            return;
        }

        p.complete(reply.result());
    });
}
```

At the end implement `yourRawApiCall` and then use it like this

```
callApiNTimes(4).onComplete(reply -> {
    if (reply.failed()) {
        // Something went wrong, do your error handling..
        return;
    }

    final YourResultType result = reply.result();

    // Do something with your result..
});
```

Antoher approach would be to put your API calls as Futures in a list
and execute this list in parallel with [CompositeFuture.all](https://vertx.io/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.reactivex.core/-composite-future/all.html), [CompositeFuture.join](https://vertx.io/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.reactivex.core/-composite-future/join.html), .. instead of one after another.